# Работа с EntityFramework создание БД

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть проект в котором нужно добавить БД с помощью EntityFramework. Проблема в том что находил множество ресурсов создание БД c использованием СУБД MS SQL Server. Мне же необходимо создать БД где в роли СУБД выступает сам EF. Буду благодарен за помощь или же за ресурс где можно ознакомится с данным процессом. Спасибо!

Comment: EF не является СУБД и не может выступать в этой роли.

Comment: смотри концепцию EF CodeFirst

Answer (score 3):

Если вы не хотите вообще сохранять данные, то у Entity Framework Core есть возможность создать БД в ОЗУ:

```
var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>()
   .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "Test")
   .Options;
```

Если же вам всё-таки нужно хранить данные, но при этом не разворачивать в системе СУБД, то база данных может храниться одним файлом в папке программы, для этого существует SQLite.